# Phalcon - Custom Model MetaData strategy

Tags: php, annotations, models, phalcon

I want to create own custom meta-data parser for Phalcon models (as current hasn't annotations for indexes and mapping one column to another parameter). Unfortunately, when I am returning mapping as array:

```
/**
 * @param \Phalcon\Mvc\ModelInterface $model
 * @param \Phalcon\DiInterface $di
 * @return array
 */
public function getColumnMaps($model, $di)
{
    $columns = [];

    /** @var \Phalcon\Annotations\Reflection $reflection */
    $reflection = $di->get('annotations')->get($model);

    foreach ($reflection->getPropertiesAnnotations() as $name => $collection) {
        if ($collection->has('Column')) {
            $columns[$collection->get('Column')->getNamedArgument('column') ?: $name] = $name;
        }
    }

    return $columns;
}
```

As I found, `Phalcon\Mvc\Model\MetaData\Strategy\Annotations` in that method returns `null`. My result is like `array` of `ID_IN_TABLE => PARAMETER_NAME`, eg. `'referer_id' => 'refererId'` which map field from database with underscore with camel-case field from model. It throws errors `Notice: Undefined index: 0` and `Notice: Undefined index: 1` when I am trying to use `find`, `count` or `findFirst` method, e.g.:

```
Users::find([
    implode(' AND ', $conditions),
    'bind' => $bind,
    'limit' => $this->getLimit(),
    'offset' => $this->getLimit() * ($this->getPage() - 1)
])
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance,
David.

Answer (score 0):

The return value of `getColumnMaps()` is supposed to look like this:

```
array(
    0 => $ordered_column_map,
    1 => $reverse_column_map
);
```

where `$ordered_column_map` is `ID_IN_TABLE => PARAMETER_NAME` amd `$reverse_column_map` is `array_flip($ordered_column_map)`.